# Open an activity from a fragment (crashes)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments, onclick

I've been trying to open an activity from a fragment using the OnClick element in a TableRow but when I run the application it closes when trying to open the activity.

This is the Java code file:

```
package com.hello.turidf;

import com.hello.turidf.R;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TabsIndexM001Help extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.m_001_help, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

public void open_m001_map(View view) {
    Intent openmap = new Intent(getActivity(),M001MapActivity.class);
    startActivity(openmap); 
    }

}
```

This is the XML code file (fragment):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
.......>

    <TableLayout
    .......>

        <TabelRow
        android:onClick="open_m001_map"
        ....>
             ........
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</ScrollBiew>
```

---

In 'M001MapActivity' activity has not yet been modified, has the code created by default.

Comment: Please post your logcat error.

Comment: Did you add your activity to the manifest?

Answer (score 3):

android:onClick execute the method passed like parameter in Activity and not in Fragment. If you want execute this method in fragment, remove this line and set OnClickListener programatically on fragment.